# Gitlab - git push fails

Tags: gitlab

I've installed Gitlab on my server and I can't push to the new repository I've created.

```
$ git remote -v
origin  gitlab@example.com:myusername/my-repository.git (fetch)
origin  gitlab@example.com:myusername/my-repository.git (push)
$ git push -u origin master
```

The `git push` command hangs for about a minute and then errors out with this message:

```
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: Fail
```

I think my problem is probably got to do with SSH:

```
$ ssh -v gitlab@example.com
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 139: Applying options for example.com
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 142: Applying options for example.com
debug1: Connecting to example.com [1.2.3.4] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa.pub type 1
debug1: identity file /home/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa.pub-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 67:33:0b:d1:72:43:6b:f3:61:b1:9e:22:ef:d7:21:d8
debug1: Host 'example.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/myusername/.ssh/known_hosts:143
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to example.com ([1.2.3.4]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_GB.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = en_GB.UTF-8
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
```

Note the the authentication seems to succeed:

```
Authenticated to example.com ([1.2.3.4]:22).
```

And I suspect the problem has got to do with:

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
```

Any clues? I spent hours googling for solution but couldn't get my head around this issue.

***EDIT:***
I've just found out this in `gitlab-shell/gitlab-shell.log`:

```
W, [2015-03-19T01:41:10.865863 #24346]  WARN -- : Failed to connect to internal API <POST https://example.com/api/v3/internal/allowed>: #<Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out - connect(2) for "example.com" port 443>
```

Comment: How did you install it? Omnibus or manual?   The internal API looks strange. I would have assumed it would be localhost:8080 or similar.   Is the gitlab service running?  gitlab-shell communicates with the gitlab server which fails. Please check the gitlab-shell configuration.

Comment: `gitlab_url: "http://localhost:8080/"` is the default in `.../gitlab-shell/config.yml`

Comment: Thanks @volker, setting `gitlab_url` to `http://localhost:8080/` fixed my issues. For some reason I had changed it to `http://example.com`. All working a treat now!

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in this, but a quick search tells me you should unmount /dev/pts, and then mount /dev/pts again.

See: https://serverfault.com/questions/351162/ssh-fails-pty-allocation-request-failed-on-channel-0

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't solve my issue. I think that my issue is Gitlab-specific.

Comment: It looks like the default gitlab user is not supposed to have a shell, and could be configured with an option line `no-pty`.
Git should not even need a shell to do it's work. It turns out that after the error message `fatal: protocol error: bad line length character:` the first 4 characters of output are printed that you would normally get if you could login with ssh. Do you have a `.bashrc` file for the gitlab user that outputs something?